# Filter @Published array in SwiftUI List removes elements in list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to implement a list functionality similar to to [Handling User Input](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) example, the interface shows a list the user can filter depending on boolean values. I want to add the following differences from the example:

- Can edit list elements from the row itself
- Move the filter logic to a ViewModel class

I've tried many approaches without success one of them:

- ViewModel:

```
    class TaskListViewModel : ObservableObject  {
    
        private var cancelables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
        private var allTasks: [Task] =
            [ Task(id: "1",name: "Task1", description: "Description", done: false),
              Task(id: "2",name: "Task2", description: "Description", done: false)]
    
        @Published var showNotDoneOnly = false
    
        @Published var filterdTasks: [Task] = []

        init() {
        
            filterdTasks = allTasks

            $showNotDoneOnly.map { notDoneOnly in
                if notDoneOnly {
                    return self.filterdTasks.filter { task in
                        !task.done
                    }
                }
                return self.filterdTasks
            }.assign(to: \.filterdTasks, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancelables)
        }
    }
```

- View:

```
struct TaskListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var taskListViewModel = TaskListViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $taskListViewModel.showNotDoneOnly) {
                    Text("Undone only")
                }.padding()
                List {
                    ForEach(taskListViewModel.filterdTasks.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                        TaskRow(task: $taskListViewModel.filterdTasks[idx])
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Tasks"))
        }
    }
}
```

- TaskRow:

```
struct TaskRow: View {
    
    @Binding var task: Task

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(task.name)
            Spacer()
            Toggle("", isOn: $task.done )
        }
    }

}
```

With this approach the list is filtered when the user enable the filter but when it is disabled the list lose the previously filtered elements. If I change the code to restore the filter elements like this:

```
    $showNotDoneOnly.map { notDoneOnly in
        if notDoneOnly {
            return self.filterdTasks.filter { task in
                !task.done
            }
        }
        return self.allTasks
    }.assign(to: \.filterdTasks, on: self)
```

The list lose the edited elements.

I've also tried making allTask property to a @Published dictionary by without success. Any idea on how to implement this? Is ther any better approach to do this in SwiftUi?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've managed to implement the list functionality whith the conditions previously listed. Based on [Cenk Bilgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190619/cenk-bilgen) answer:

- ListView:

```
struct TaskListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TaskListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $viewModel.filterDone) {
                    Text("Filter done")
                }.padding()
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.filter(), id: \.self) { task in
                        TaskRow(task: task)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Tasks"))
        }.onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchTasks()
        }
    }
}
```

- TaskRow:

```
struct TaskRow: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var task: TaskViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(task.name)
            Spacer()
            Toggle("", isOn: $task.done )
        }
    }

}
```

- TaskListViewModel

```
class TaskListViewModel : ObservableObject  {
    
    private var cancelables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    @Published var filterDone = false

    @Published var tasks: [TaskViewModel] = []
    
    func filter() -> [TaskViewModel]  {
        filterDone ? tasks.filter { !$0.done } : tasks
    }
    
    func fetchTasks() {
        let id = 0
        [
         TaskViewModel(name: "Task \(id)", description: "Description"),
         TaskViewModel(name: "Task \(id + 1)", description: "Description")
        ].forEach { add(task: $0) }
    }
    
    private func add(task: TaskViewModel) {
        tasks.append(task)
        task.objectWillChange
            .sink { self.objectWillChange.send() }
            .store(in: &cancelables)

    }
}
```

Notice here each TaskViewModel will propagate objectWillChange event to TaskListViewModel to update the filter when a task is marked as completed.

- TaskViewModel:

```
class TaskViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String { name }
    
    let name: String
    let description: String
    
    @Published var done: Bool = false
    
    init(name: String, description: String, done: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.done = done
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: TaskViewModel, rhs: TaskViewModel) -> Bool {
      lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
      
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
      hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
}
```

This is the main difference from the original approach: Changing the row model from a simple struct included as @Binding to an ObservableObject

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI architecture is really just state and view. Here, it's the state of the Task that you are most interested in (done/undone). Make the Task an Observable class that publishes it's done/undone state change. Bind the UI toggle switch in TaskRow directly to that done/undone in the Task model (remove the intermediary list of indexes), then you don't need any logic to publish state changes manually.

The second state for the app is filtered/unfiltered for the list. That part it seems you already have down.

This is one possible way to do it.
EDIT: Here's a more full example on how to keep the data state and view separate. The Task model is the central idea here.

```
@main
struct TaskApp: App {
  @StateObject var model = Model()
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      TaskListView()
        .environmentObject(model)
    }
  }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
  @Published var tasks: [Task] = [
    Task(name: "Task1", description: "Description"),
    Task(name: "Task2", description: "Description")
  ] // some initial sample data
  func updateTasks() {
    //
  }
}

class Task: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id: String { name }
  let name, description: String
  @Published var done: Bool = false
  init(name: String, description: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
  }
  static func == (lhs: Task, rhs: Task) -> Bool {
    lhs.id == rhs.id
  }
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
  }
}

struct TaskListView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
  var filter: ([Task]) -> [Task] = { $0.filter { $0.done } }
  @State private var applyFilter = false
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $applyFilter) {
          Text("Undone only")
        }.padding()
        List {
          ForEach(
            (applyFilter ? filter(model.tasks) : model.tasks), id: \.self) { task in
            TaskRow(task: task)
          }
        }
      }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Tasks"))
    }
  }
}

struct TaskRow: View {
  @ObservedObject var task: Task
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(task.name)
            Spacer()
          Toggle("", isOn: $task.done).labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cenk. Would it be possible to move the filter logic to a ViewModel class as I asked? The idea is to load the tasks in that ViewModel class from a service for instance, so the initialization of the task array should be done there too.

Comment: I've tried the example and it's not working properly: The filtered list inside ForEach has different size than de TaskRow list. It doesnt crash because the filtered list is always smaller than de original

Comment: The task list and the filter logic is separate from the view. I put default values in to match what you had, but really it would be better to leave them out. Change the `var tasks = ...` and `var filter = ...`. To just `lets` then pass the data and filter closure to the View from somewhere else (for the actual task data and environment variable would be better).

Comment: As for the index crashing, it shouldn't because the filtered list will always be <= than the unfiltered list. However you are right it is kind of confusing, it's better and safer to ForEach over the actual Tasks and not the index of Tasks. Just need to make Tasks conform to Hashable.

Comment: Thanks again for the edit. It's clarifying me concetps. The decisión of applying or not the filter is still inside the view: 'applyFilter ? filter(model.tasks) : model.tasks' is it possible to move it to 'Model' class?

Comment: The filter is an argument to the View, so it can come from anywhere. So you can keep the filter value in the Model class or a separate FilterModel or keep it nowhere and just specify it directly as an argument. It does look like it's part of the TaskListView, but that's just a sample-code default value if none is passed.

Comment: The filter function is a parameter but the decision of apply it or not is not part of the function and it belongs to the view. The function could be anything like "highlight done task" for instance, but the decision of apply it or not is not parametrized and cannot be tested isolated from the view

Comment: Having a default implementation makes it look like the View handles the filtering (it only does if you don't give it one as an argument), I agree I should have changed the var to a let and taken out the default implementation to clarify it. Call the TaskListView as `TaskListView(filter: { $0 // for no filter for example  })` or if the filter is stored in a model `TaskListView(filter: { filterModel.filter })`. It's all testable. It's hard to write SwiftUI code that isn't testable.

Comment: Other problem I've noticed is when the filter is on and finish a task, the task remains in the list. Is it possible to update the filter when an individual value of the list is changed?

Comment: one thought is something like have the TaskView observe changes to it's Task (only published properties will publish though). Add ```.onReceive(task.$done, perform: { print("done is \($0)") // set a new value for filter, wherever it is but it should be Published or State, to cause update \\ filter = { $0.filter { $0.name.hasPrefix("A")} }  })```